# How to remove unwanted character when using Reduce and paste to concatenate strings

Tags: r

I have strings of url and arguments and I'm concatenating them using `paste.`

```
base_url <- "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/homr/services/station/search?"
args <- c("state=CA", "headersOnly=true")

combined_url <- Reduce(function(x,y) paste0(x, "&", y), x=args, init=base_url)
> combined_url
[1] "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/homr/services/station/search?&state=CA&headersOnly=true"
```

The combined URL has an unwanted `&` between the base URL and arguments. How do I concatenate the base URL and arguments without the `&` in between?

I want something like this:

```
> combined_url
[1] "http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/homr/services/station/search?state=CA&headersOnly=true"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use paste two times. Reduce is used for something else.

```r
combined_url <- paste0(base_url,paste(args,collapse="&"))
```